# on div click change button text inside, on click of another div reset the previous text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have three columns all with a show button, I need the text of the button to change when the 'advice-card' div is clicked to 'Hide' and I need the other buttons to switch back to show if a different 'advice-card' div is clicked. Thank you

```
<div id="general-advice" class="col-sm advice-card">
<div class="advice-card-footer">
    <p class="advice-cost-disclaimer">Cost: Included with membership - no additional cost.</p>
    <button>Show</button>
</div></div>


<div id="super-advice" class="col-sm advice-card">
<div class="advice-card-footer">
    <p class="advice-cost-disclaimer">Cost: Included with membership - no additional cost.</p>
    <button>Show</button>
</div></div>


<div id="retirement-advice" class="col-sm advice-card">
<div class="advice-card-footer">
    <p class="advice-cost-disclaimer">Cost: Included with membership - no additional cost.</p>
    <button>Show</button>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and how and why to make [mre]... In short, you need to share your JS code and what have you tried so far, and we will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
    <div id="general-advice" class="col-sm advice-card">
    <div class="advice-card-footer">
    <p class="advice-cost-disclaimer">Cost: Included with membership - no additional cost.</p>
    <button class="hideShowButton" id="button-0" onclick="hideShow(this.id)">Show</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="super-advice" class="col-sm advice-card">
    <div class="advice-card-footer">
    <p class="advice-cost-disclaimer">Cost: Included with membership - no additional cost.</p>
    <button class="hideShowButton" id="button-1" onclick="hideShow(this.id)">Show</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="retirement-advice" class="col-sm advice-card">
    <div class="advice-card-footer">
    <p class="advice-cost-disclaimer">Cost: Included with membership - no additional cost.</p>
    <button class="hideShowButton" id="button-2" onclick="hideShow(this.id)">Show</button>
    </div>
    </div>


<script>
    function hideShow(id){
        let i = 0; 
        let currentElement;
        let clickedElement;
        let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("hideShowButton");
        for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i ++){
            currentElement  = elements[i];
            if(currentElement.id != id){
                currentElement.innerHTML = "Show";
            }
            else{
                clickedElement = currentElement;
            }
        }

        if(clickedElement.innerHTML == "Hide"){
            clickedElement.innerHTML = "Show";
        }else{
            clickedElement.innerHTML = "Hide";
        }         

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you looking for because you didn't share your js code, but maybe below solution will be helpful for you.

```js
jQuery(function($){
$('.advice-card').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(e){
if($(this).hasClass('active-card')){
$(this).removeClass('active-card');
$(this).find('button').text('Show');
} else {
$(this).addClass('active-card').siblings().removeClass('active-card');
$(this).find('button').text('hide');
$(this).siblings().find('button').text('Show');
}
});
});
});
```

```css
.advice-card {
margin: 2px auto;
width: 400px;
height: auto;
padding: 24px;
border: 1px solid #eee;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
display: flex;
}

.advice-card.active-card {
border: 1px solid red;
}

.advice-card .advice-card-footer {
width: 100%;
}

.advice-card button {
color: #fff;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
background: blue;
border: 0px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 12px 24px;
float: right;
display: inline-block;
}

.advice-card.active-card button {
background: red;
}

.advice-card .advice-card-footer p {
margin: 0px;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
height: 0px;
transition: all ease-in-out 0s;
clear: both;
}


.advice-card.active-card .advice-card-footer p {
margin: 24px auto;
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
height: auto;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="general-advice" class="col-sm advice-card">
<div class="advice-card-footer">
    <p class="advice-cost-disclaimer">Cost: Included with membership - no additional cost.</p>
    <button>Show</button>
</div></div>


<div id="super-advice" class="col-sm advice-card">
<div class="advice-card-footer">
    <p class="advice-cost-disclaimer">Cost: Included with membership - no additional cost.</p>
    <button>Show</button>
</div></div>


<div id="retirement-advice" class="col-sm advice-card">
<div class="advice-card-footer">
    <p class="advice-cost-disclaimer">Cost: Included with membership - no additional cost.</p>
    <button>Show</button>
</div></div>
```